# Non-Isomorph trees of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

Please consider this graph

[image]

How many non-Isomorph trees with 4 vertex has this graph?

Is there any formula that show number of non-Isomorph trees with $n$ vertices?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two 4-node trees up to isomorphism: the straight line and the Y-shaped graph. The above graph contains both of them.

For the number of trees with $n$ vertices, Wikipedia links here : http://oeis.org/A000055 .

Comment: Thanks.You mean that this graph has 2 non-Isomorphic trees? I can't use the link.Can you please add Wikipedia link?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Enumeration <-- Scroll to "Unlabelled trees".

Comment: I think it has one more non isomorphic tree.Top node with 4 edge is a tree.Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, which tree? I don't understand.

Comment: Top node with 4 edge of 5 edge connected to it is another tree

Comment: But a tree with four edges would have 5 vertices...

Comment: Yes I'm sorry.You are right